# Filter, dual ideal,definition of $\liminf_I \lambda$

Tags: cardinals, limsup-and-liminf, filters, duality-theorems

We have this https://shelah.logic.at/papers/506/ definition of $\lim \inf_I \bar{\lambda}$ in 1.1(3): for $I$ a filter on $\kappa$ let $I^+=2^\kappa \setminus I$. $$\lim \inf_I \bar{\lambda}=\min\{\mu:\{i<\kappa:\lambda_i\leq\mu\}\in I^+\}.$$
But then *always* $\lim \inf_I \bar{\lambda}=0$, since $\emptyset\notin I$, so
$\emptyset\in I^+$.
Where is the typo in this definition? What is the correct, intended form of it?

Comment: $I$ should be an ideal, not a filter here.

Comment: Note that, at the top of the page from which you quoted the definition, item 1.1 Notation 1) says that $I$ and $J$ denote ideals, and it also says a few lines later that "we do not always distinguish strictly between an ideal on $\kappa$ and the dual filter on $\kappa$."  Not that this justifies the misstatment that you quoted, but it does suggest where to look for the error.

Comment: What about the immediately following 2 lines,$\lim \sup$ and  **atom**,is $I$ also an ideal,and not a filter?

Comment: Yes, $I$ should be an ideal in all of item 3.